# Slow internet only on my mac - same ethernet gets 100mbs on other laptop

Tags: macos, networking, mac, speed

Wondering if someone could help me diagnose a network problem. My Macbook pro running OSX seems to have a connection bottleneck. I have 100mbs on my other laptop but when I take the same Ethernet cable and put it into my mac i'm getting less than 1mbs.

Any ideas? I'm getting equally slow speeds on WiFi.

I've restarted and don't see anything on activity monitor that could be stealing bandwidth.

Comment: What are you using to measure?

Comment: Used speedof.me and speedtest.net

Comment: Could you share your settings on the MBP

Comment: What sort of LAN port do you have on this device?   Based on how you describe the problem it sounds like you have a 10/100 LAN port which would explain the different speeds compared to your other device which has a 10/100/1000 LAN port.

Comment: What settings would you like and where would I find them?

Comment: WiFi also could be explained by slower hardware.  I will wait until the author provides the information I requested to come to any conclusions.

Comment: In terminal "airport -I" will show it

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences -> Network, if your WiFi setting is above your Ethernet setting (when both are connected) in the list on the left, then only WiFi will be used.  To test your Ethernet speed you would have to turn WiFi off or make sure it is lower in the list than Ethernet.  To change the order, click the gear icon at the bottom of the list and choose "Set Service Order...".

This may not be your problem, because MacBook Pros have been able to get more than 1mb/s over wifi for quite a long time.  However, if both wifi and ethernet are running at the same speed it is worth checking.